# express-validator usage with ESM modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules, express-validator

I tried to import into an ESM module with this syntax in Node.js v8.7.0 with `--experimental-modules` flag:

```
import { check, validationResult } from 'express-validator/check';
import { matchedData, sanitize } from 'express-validator/filter';
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
(node:29028) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
SyntaxError: The requested module does not provide an export named 'check'
    at checkComplete (internal/loader/ModuleJob.js:86:27)
    at moduleJob.linked.then (internal/loader/ModuleJob.js:69:11)
    at <anonymous>
```

What is the correct usage with ESM modules turned on with `--experimental-modules` flag?

I tested with `@std/esm` package also. It only works of I turn `cjs: true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because, in Node.js, CommonJS modules imported via `import` only have a default export*.

If the module you're importing is not an ES Module (which is the case of express-validator), then all you can do is something like this:

```
import checkAPIs from 'express-validator/check';
import filterAPIs from 'express-validator/filter';

const { check, validationResult } = checkAPIs;
const { matchedData } = filterAPIs;
```

<sub>* Source: https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c</sub>

Comment: Thank You! It works perfectly both with `--experimental-modules` and `@std/esm`.

Answer (score 2):

Use This...

```js
import validator from 'express-validator'
const { check, validationResult } = validator
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, when doing `from 'express-validator/check'`, for example, it says, `requires to express-validator/check are deprecated.You should just use require("express-validator") instead.`  Ironically, so are CommonJS modules to some extent.

```
import validator from 'express-validator'
const { body } = validator
```